# Non-Linear, Non-Stationary spectral analysis methods! When and where?

Tags: fourier-transform, wavelet, hilbert-transform

I have been reading about non-linear non-stationary signal analysis methods and it seems to do this type of analysis the go-to method is the Empirical Mode Decomposition (EMD), then Hilbert Transform (HT) to get instantaneous phase and frequency.

However I have been doing some analysis on a non-linear, non-stationary signal by splitting the time signal into intervals with a Hanning window and Fourier transforming each interval which I think might also be the idea behind the Short Time Fourier Transform (STFT), although I am not sure.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this method, and why the EMD / HT method is more advantageous? I have also seen wavelet analysis used in similar cases, is this something I should look into?

Comment: Don't know about non-linear as a generic problem but my old "hobby horse" is Wavelets for what this problem sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

Non-linearity and non-stationarity are **non-properties**. Without more details, they do not say much about the methods that may perform well, and moreover the  choice depends a lot on what you really do: analysis, feature extraction, enhancement, filtering, component separation, restoration? What follows are typical sets of tools you could use:

- Your moving-window-Fourier definitely has some STFT flavors, and there are many non-linear extensions: [bilinear or quadratic time–frequency distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_time%E2%80%93frequency_distribution) (Wigner-Ville, Choi–Williams, Rihaczek)
- Non-linearity may come from changing the classical energy preservation into other norms, like robust DFTs (under an $\ell_1$ norm minimization), see for instance [Robust $L$-estimation based forms of signal transforms and time-frequency representations](https://doi.org/10.1109/tsp.2003.812739), see also [Using different algorithms/formulas to create spectrograms](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/59022/15892)
- Some methods also alleviate the hypothesis that signal formation is linear: variance-stabilizing transforms,  cepstral analysis or [homomorphic signal processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_filtering) (linear transforms applied in a $\log$ domain)
- Generalizations of linear approaches in polynomial or rational fraction modeling, with a recent interest in [Rational Optimization for Nonlinear Reconstruction with Approximate $\ell_0$ Penalization](https://doi.org/10.1109/tsp.2018.2890065).

All of the above can be combined somehow, like EMD at different scales in [Intrinsic multi-scale analysis: a multi-variate empirical mode decomposition framework](https://dx.doi.org/10.1098%2Frspa.2014.0709). EMD has many uses and [some known limitations at the same time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Huang_transform#Limitations).